# Trouble Importing a material Button from one class and utilizing it in another

Tags: flutter, import, materialbutton

So I'm picking up flutter, and slowly but surely starting to learn it but am still very new to it at the moment. I've created a Material Button in one class (Named LoginButton), representing a login button, and want to utilize it in another class that creates the actual page for the login button to be used on. I am however struggling with placing said button into the scaffold I'm using on this page.

[What do I need to do to link to another file with my button widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69047141/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-link-to-another-file-with-my-button-widgets)
My understanding from the following post was that using LoginButton(), would be fine, however i'm getting an error saying "LoginButton isn't a function.
Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'LoginButton'." Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I've marked the line causing the error, its at the bottom of MyHomePage.dart

LoginButton.dart

```
class LoginButton extends StatelessWidget {
 static const String routeName = '/LoginButton';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();

    return Material(
        elevation: 5.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        color: Colors.black,
        child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text("Login"),
            onPressed: () async {
              var result = await Authenticator()
                  .signIn(email: email.text, password: password.text);
              if (result) {
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    // 1. make this a page, make a class for login and extend it to register
                    return Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            title: Text("HomeChef")),
                        drawer: Drawer(
                            child: ListView(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            DrawerHeader(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                'My Account',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 24,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.person_outline_sharp),
                              title: Text('Profile'),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                              title: Text("Liked Recipies"),
                            ),
                            ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline),
                              title: Text('Playlists'),
                            )
                          ],
                        )));
                  },
                ));
              }
            }));
}
  }
```

MyHomePage.dart

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final emailField = TextField(
      obscureText: false,
      controller: email,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Email",
          border:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

// Text field for The first name of a User when registering

// Text field for a password when Registering/ Logging in
    final passwordField = TextField(
      obscureText: true,
      style: style,
      controller: password,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Password",
          border:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final signUpButon = Material(
        elevation: 5.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        color: Colors.black,
        child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text("Sign Up"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context); // returning user to login page
            }));

    final firstNameField = TextField(
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "First Name",
          border:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

// Text field for the last name of a User when registering
    final lastNameField = TextField(
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          hintText: "Last Name",
          border:
              OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final registerButon = Material(
        elevation: 5.0,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        color: Colors.black,
        child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text("Create An Account"),
            onPressed: () {
              // Changing routes
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Scaffold(
                      body: Center(
                          child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(height: 45.0),
                          firstNameField,
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 25.0,
                          ),
                          lastNameField,
                          SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                          emailField,
                          SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                          passwordField,
                          SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                          signUpButon,
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )));
                },
              ));
            }));

// Setting scene for intial Route
// Button for Users to create a new account
// Upon clicking, will switch routes to a new Route
// with new fields
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 45.0),
            emailField,
            SizedBox(height: 25.0),
            passwordField,
            SizedBox(height: 35.0),
            LoginButton(), // This is the line in question causing the error
            SizedBox(height: 35.0),
            registerButon,
            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )));
  }

  final TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
}
```

Comment: Did you import the login button file ?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to include those in the code sample

Comment: So upon looking over my import statements, I had imported both 'LoginButton' and 'LoginButton.dart', causing the error. Can't believe I didn't catch this, Thank You!!!